# Resources to read more about/learn how implied pricing works

Tags: futures, pricing

I was looking at this video today:

http://www.cmegroup.com/education/interactive/webinars-archived/implied-price-functionality.html

on implied pricing. And am aware that implied orders/pricing exists in ICE as well. I found it difficult to follow (the video) beyond the vanilla examples and was wondering what other resources might break this down a little more that I can search for or reference to understand implied orders/pricing/book in these markets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking at this recently and found the following resources very useful:

- [CME Implied Orders (IN/OUT)](https://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Implied+Orders)
- [CME Implied Orders Examples (IN/OUT)](https://www.cmegroup.com/confluence/display/EPICSANDBOX/Implied+Orders+-+Examples)
- [ICE Implied FAQ](https://www.theice.com/publicdocs/technology/Additional_Implieds_FAQ.pdf)
- [ICE Implied Example](https://www.theice.com/publicdocs/technology/ICE_Derivations_Test_3_Months.xls) - link in the ICE Implied FAQ aswell
- Trading Technologies Calculating

  - [Calculating Implied](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/x-trader/trading-and-the-market-window/calculating-implieds/)
  - [Calculating Implied Ins](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/x-trader/trading-and-the-market-window/calculating-implied-ins/)
  - [Calculating Implied Outs](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/x-trader/trading-and-the-market-window/calculating-implied-ins/)
  - [Calculating Implied from Implieds](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/x-trader/trading-and-the-market-window/calculating-implieds-from-implieds/) - Useful to understand what is meant by the word **generation** in the implied context